# Selenium: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to scrape this page: http://www.ebay.com/itm/311419628966 using the following XPath:

```
• .//*[@id='ds_div']
• .//*[@id='pdets']
• .//*[@id='centercolumn']/
```

But they all throw NoSuchElementException.

This is odd because when I inspect the page with Firebug I'm able to locate the element easily.

Comment: It might be possible that those elements take bit long time to load , can you please put wait command before element find? and then check.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm already using an implicit wait of 7 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements with those `id` values are inside a `frame`. You need to switch into its context:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("desc_ifr");
```

Comment: Thanks. Your a genius! May I ask where in the HTML code did you find its an iframe? I suspected it may be an iFrame but did not find the term iFrame anywhere let alone the term "desc_ifr". Where did you find it?

Comment: @JimKim yeah, there is an `iframe` element with `id="desc_ifr"`. I usually just look up the parents of the desired node and, once I see an `iframe` or `frame` there, I know that I have to change the context of the search and switch to the `iframe`/`frame`. Glad to help and don't forget to accept the answer so we can "resolve" the topic. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted. Thanks for explanation.